# PCA analysis wrong output

Tags: r

That's the example data:

```
structure(c(368113, 87747.35, 508620.5, 370570.5, 87286.5, 612728, 
55029, 358521, 2802880, 2045399.5, 177099, 317974.5, 320687.95, 
6971292.55, 78949, 245415.95, 50148.5, 67992.5, 97634, 56139.5, 
371719.2, 80182.7, 612078.5, 367822.5, 80691, 665190.65, 28283.5, 
309720, 2853241.5, 1584324, 135482.5, 270959, 343879.1, 6748208.5, 
71534.9, 258976, 28911.75, 78306, 56358.7, 46783.5, 320882.85, 
53098.3, 537383.5, 404505.5, 89759.7, 624120.55, 40406, 258183.5, 
3144610.45, 1735583.5, 122013.5, 249741, 362585.35, 5383869.15, 
23172.2, 223704.45, 40543.7, 68522.5, 43187.05, 29745, 356058.5, 
89287.25, 492242.5, 452135.5, 97253.55, 575661.95, 65739.5, 334703.5, 
3136065, 1622936.5, 131381.5, 254362, 311496.3, 5627561, 68210.6, 
264610.1, 45851, 65010.5, 32665.5, 39957.5, 362476.75, 59451.65, 
548279, 345096.5, 93363.5, 596444.2, 11052.5, 252812, 2934035, 
1732707.55, 208409.5, 208076.5, 437764.25, 16195882.45, 77461.25, 
205803.85, 30437.5, 75540, 49576.75, 48878, 340380.5, 43785.35, 
482713, 340315, 64308.5, 517859.85, 11297, 268993.5, 3069028.5, 
1571889, 157561, 217596.5, 400610.65, 5703337.6, 50640.65, 197477.75, 
40070, 66619, 81564.55, 41436.5, 367592.3, 64954.9, 530093, 432025, 
87212.5, 553901.65, 20803.5, 333940.5, 3027254.5, 1494468, 195221, 
222895.5, 494429.45, 7706885.75, 60633.35, 192827.1, 29857.5, 
81001.5, 112588.65, 68904.5, 338822.5, 56868.15, 467350, 314526.5, 
105568, 749456.1, 19597.5, 298939.5, 2993199.2, 1615231.5, 229185.5, 
280433.5, 360156.15, 5254889.1, 79369.5, 175434.05, 40907.05, 
70919, 65720.15, 53054.5), .Dim = c(20L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Anne", "Greg", "thomas", "Chris", "Gerard", "Monk", "Mart", 
    "Mutr", "Aeqe", "Tor", "Gaer", "Toaq", "Kolr", "Wera", "Home", 
    "Terlo", "Kulte", "Mercia", "Loki", "Herta"), c("Day_Rep1", 
    "Day_Rep2", "Day_Rep3", "Day_Rep4", "Day2_Rep1", "Day2_Rep2", 
    "Day2_Rep3", "Day2_Rep4")))
```

I would like to perform a nice PCA analysis. I expect that replicates from Day will be nicely correlated with each other and replicates from Day2 together. I was trying to perform some analysis using the code below:

```
## log transform
data_log <- log(data[, 1:8])
#vec_EOD_EON
dt_PCA <- prcomp(data_log,
                           center = TRUE,
                           scale. = TRUE)

library(devtools)
install_github("ggbiplot", "vqv")

library(ggbiplot)
g <- ggbiplot(dt_PCA, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, 
              groups = colnames(dt_PCA), ellipse = TRUE, 
              circle = TRUE)
g <- g + scale_color_discrete(name = "")
g <- g + theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
               legend.position = 'top')
print(g)
```

However, the output is not what I am looking for:

[image: Output]

but I am looking for something more like that:

[image: Desired output]

I would like to use dots for each row in the data and different colors for each of the replicate. Would be cool to use the similar colors for Day replicates and as well for Day2.

Obtained data with ggplot:

[image]

Comment: I dont't get your question. Is it about the plot, i.e. you want to know how to create colored points? Or is it about the PCA which displays no distinct groups?

Comment: The idea is to plot them as distinct groups using colors. As you see there is an experiment. Let's say that Day is a control and Day2 is a treatment. For each of them I have four replicates. I would assume that all replicates for Day will be highly correlated with each other and will stay as a one group on the plot and the same for replicates in Day2. Maybe I am mistaken and it will look different. However, from the graph which I have plotted I can't see anything. You can suggest any other PCA approach if you have better idea. You know my goal.

Comment: All your variables are highly correlated. A PCA will always more or less look like a horizontal line in this case

Comment: So, please help me with adding a colors into my PCA analysis and I would be grateful if you would suggest any other approach for comparing this data... and try to visualize potential difference between control and treatment (Day vs Day2)...

Comment: Your plot has your *rows* as points (10 of them) but you want to colour them according to the column? Or do you want different colours for the arrows?

Comment: I would like to have them colour according to column they belong.

Comment: The columns in your initial dataset are the variables, right? By doing PCA you are transforming your variables and a given datapoint like `(PCA1, PCA2)` does not 'belong' to a column: It is a combination of two mixtures of your columns. I **think** from the way you describe your problem, there may be a missing piece of the puzzle, namely an additional label (like in the iris dataset), that is not affected by the PCA. Perhaps PCA is not a suitable method for you.

Comment: @KenS. I think this additional information is hidden in the column names. `Day` and `Day2` are the conditions, so basically the colours in the iris data, the `Rep` information are the individual points. He needs to transfer the data like I did in my example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine you save your data into `df`.

```
library(ggplot2)
pc_df <- prcomp(t(df), scale.=TRUE)
pc_table <- as.data.frame(pc_df$x[,1:2]) # extracting 1st and 2nd component

experiment_regex <- '(^[^_]+)_Rep(\\d+)' # extracting replicate and condition from your experiment names
pc_table$replicate <- as.factor(sub(experiment_regex,'\\2', rownames(pc_table)))
pc_table$condition <- as.factor(sub(experiment_regex,'\\1', rownames(pc_table)))

ggplot(pc_table, aes(PC1, PC2, color=condition, shape=replicate)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab(sprintf('PC1 - %.1f%%', # extracting the percentage of each PC and print it on the axes
               summary(pc_df)$importance[2,1] * 100)) +
  ylab(sprintf('PC2 - %.1f%%', 
               summary(pc_df)$importance[2,2] * 100))
```

The first thing you have to do, to get your data in the correct shape is to transform it using `t()`. This might be already what you are looking for.

I prefer to do the plots with my own function and I wrote the steps down to get a nice plot with `ggplot2`.

[image: example figure]

**UPDATE:**

Since you were asking in the comments. Here is an example where an experiment was repeated on a different day. Replicate 1 and 2 on one day, and a few days later replicate 3 and 4.
The difference on both days are higher then the changes in the conditions (day has 49% variance, experiment has only 20% variance explained).
This is not a good experiment and should be repeated! 
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think it worked well for my original data. I added the output from your code in main question. I would like to know what do you think about that plot and how to interpret it ? What does it tell me ? I know that's not a question regarding R or something but I would like to know the opinion from someone "outside". Thanks! Deserved 50 points

Comment: Your condition spreads on the second dimension but not on the first, which is most of the time a bad sign. But in your case both axes explain only around 20% of the variance, so it is not to bad :-) It depends on what you are looking for. Maybe you can figure out what are done different in con red rep 1 2 compared to 3 4 (as well as con green rep 1 4 to 2 3)... This could explain why there is a higher variance on the 1 component

Comment: The general idea was to show that replicates of one condition correlates (red or blue) correlates "better" than replicates between the conditions. Is it a case ? or different analysis should be performed ?

Comment: This is something I can not answer for you, sorry, I need more background etc. And to picture is a bit borderline to decide this. You might need other kind of analysis as well. Sorry, there is no clear yes or no!

Comment: Final question. You were so helpful.  What about ignoring the replicates now and just using 2 conditions. There should not be a shape difference. I mean that I would like to use each row as a separate dot. Is it possible ?

Comment: It is possible but I wouldn't recommend it. I mean your data shows that the main driver in your data is not the condition but something else... Imagine u r analysing two species at different temperatures. What u expect is, that the main driver of changes is the temperature... So this should be displayed as PC1 with the most variability. If it is on the second PC and on the PC1 is maybe the sex of the species, this would mean, that the sex is more important in your study then the temperature and it is much more difficult to claim anything from the results describing the temperature.

Comment: I got your point. Out of the curiosity, could you show me such plot ? I will not use it, however it would indicate for me what can be wrong with my data. I think I could not explain correctly from the beginning what is my data... Can you help with such plot ?